# Where is uni.inc file?

Tags: ida

In the IDA Pro generated asm code, I see this line:

```
include uni.inc ; see unicode subdir of ida for info on unicode
```

I don't find unicode subdir nor do I find uni.inc file...

Could any one give me some help? Thank you!

Comment: First I thought it's in the SDK, but it isn't. Not FLAIR or IDS Utils or loadint either.

Comment: What happens when you remove that "include uni.inc" line and try to compile the code?

Comment: @JasonGeffner I think there are some issues with unicode data definition like aA __unicode__ "aAa". There is obvious no definition of this macro when using masm to re-assemble it.

Comment: Probably best to email support@hex-rays.com

Comment: @JasonGeffner thank you! eventually I rewrite this macro, using masm's unicode macro